# Why does GridView reset its values to what it was before user edits?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

If I bind *GridView* (via *DataSourceID* attribute) to *SqlDataSource* and set *SelectCommand* and *UpdateCommand* attributes, then everything works perfectly.

But if  we manually call *GridView.DataBind* inside *Page_Load()*, then *SqlDataSource* doesn’t perform any updates, even though *SqlDataSource.Updating* and *SqlDataSource.Updated* events do fire when GridView’s Update button is clicked. I think this is due to the fact that *GridView* resets to what it was before the user edits:

a) Why does *GridView* reset its values if we manually call *DataBind()* inside *Page_Load()*?

b) Since *Update* operation doesn’t work when manually calling *DataBind*, I would then assume that *Delete* operation also wouldn’t work, but it does. Why?

cheers

Answer (score 1):

I believe Page_Load runs before your changes take place, thus you bind the old data before you run the updates

Wrap the bind in a If Not IsPostBack when under Page_Load, i believe that will fix your problem.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking.I know that in order for Update operation to succeed, then on postback we shouldn't manually call DataBind.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assign the GridView with source and also databind it. Something along the lines of the following code:

```
Page_Load 

if(!Page.IsPostBack) 
{
    gv1.DataSource = GetData(); 
    gv1.DataBind(); 
}
```